# How to optimize code in Python? Vectorize?

Tags: python, numpy, random, vectorization

Suppose I have a vector `myVec` and I want to sum 1260 elements of it for 10 000 times.

I wrote the following code:

```
newVector = [sum(np.random.choice(myVec, 1260, replace=True)) for _ in range(10000)]
```

how can I optimize it and save time?

Can I vectorize the code?

Comment: `np.random.choice(myVec, size=(1260, 10000), replace=True).sum(axis=1)` (I might have the axis wrong)

Comment: @PaulH. That is probably the optimal answer. Pretty sure you got the right axis.

Comment: That was crazy! From 15 seconds to 2 seconds!

Comment: If you put the answer I can accept it

Comment: P.S. are you sure the axis is the proper one? I guess is axis=0, but no problem at all!